# SQL - find all codes in subset of years

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a table as follows:

```
Codes
year |  code   |
----------------
2009 | 10001   |
2009 | 10002   |
2009 | 10003   |

2010 | 10001   |
2010 | 10002   |
2010 | 10004   |

2011 | 10001   |
2011 | 10005   |
2011 | 10010   |
```

**How do I find all codes which are present in a subset of the years**.  For example, if I want to find all codes which are present in both year 2009 and 2010 (and not necessarily 2011) I should get `10001` and `10002` since these are both present in 2009 and 2010.  The following is incorrect but I want something like:

```
SELECT code FROM Codes
GROUP BY code
HAVING year in (2009,2010)
```

Comment: What is your RDBMs?

Comment: @JorgeCampos sqlite3

Comment: How many years would you like to match in a single statement?

Comment: I had an answer based on a misunderstanding. @JorgeCampos drew my attention to this, and I have deleted it and supplied a new answer which I think will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Code
 From  Codes
 Where Year In (2009,2010,2011)
 Group By Code
 Having count(Distinct Year)=3
```

Should return only `10001`

Comment: How to solve if it was passed three years as parameters and they aren't subsequent? Liked this approach though.

Comment: This is definitely the most succinct if the years are contiguous.  And for most of my purposes they will be so I will accept this answer.  Curious if there is a elegant solution if the years are not subsequent.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks for the update, I think I finally woke up and learned something.  If I understand correctly  the `Where Year In` clause applies 'first' so to speak, so that when counting distinct year I only need to make sure the count is equal to the number of years I want.

Comment: That's is great. +1

Comment: @JorgeCampos Very kind.  Like most of us, "Standing on the shoulders of GIANTS"  :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve that is to use `INTERSECT` operation

```
 select code from codes where year=2009
 intersect
 select code from codes where year=2010;
```

This will give you:

```
code
10001
10002
```

Problems with this approach is that you will have to add an `intersect` for each filter.

Comment: This is interesting but you pointed out the drawback, which is the need for many intersections.  So far its the only solution if the years are not subsequent though.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you can find what you want with the following query:

```
SELECT code
FROM codes
WHERE year IN (2009,2010)
GROUP BY code
HAVING count(*)=2;
```

Explanation:

- Filter to only matching years
- Group by codes will give you distict codes, and, among others, the number of rows for each group (`count(*)`).
- HAVING will filter for codes which have 2 occurrences. This implies that they must match both the years.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This is very similar to the accepted answer and works just as well in this case.  I can only accept one though.

Comment: @mikev3 You’re welcome. FWIW I don’t think you have accepted his answer. You should do that my selecting the check mark on its left.

Comment: thanks again, I meant to but didn't actually click it!

Answer (score 0):

your sol:-

SELECT code FROM Codes 
WHERE year >= 2009 AND year <= 2011;

Comment: I need codes which are present in BOTH years simultaneously as indicated by the desired result.  I'll update to highlight this point.